# Atomicity of mongoose validators and save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, atomic

From the docs, validators are pre-save hooks. But are the validate and save operations together atomic?

So let's say I create a schema for an inventory counting the 'quantity' of a product and setting a validator (min=0). Suppose now that the 'quantity' is 1 and two requests come in at the same time for a $inc -1 operation on quantity. Both validators would pass and the two saves would go through resulting in a 'quantity' of -1. Am I right about this?

Secondly, to solve this would I require a transaction where I manually validate the document again after save?